# 2 actionbar tabs don't fill a screen width on FULLHD (xxhdpi) Android device

Tags: android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

I have required styles (from designer) applied on my TABs used in Actionbar for navigation and I use Actionbar Sherlock. They look perfectly from ldpi to xhdpi devices, but situation changes on xxhdpi devices.
I have only 2tabs and except mentioned styling, I have the same code as Sherlock DEMO app in "Tab Navigation". I found 2 older simmilar questions not answered yet.

[Stacked ActionBar tab bar not filling parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979327/stacked-actionbar-tab-bar-not-filling-parent)
(I've got a simmilar problem, centered tabs. Sorry for inconvenience, I can't attach images because of rep points.)
and
[action bar tabs not fill screen in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887191/action-bar-tabs-not-fill-screen-in-android)

Since the time of their posts, this is not only the issue of tablets, but now, there are many FULLHD (flagship) smartphones and this is becomming the big "design" issue.

I want my 2tabs to fill/match the full width of ANY device size, so in my case to fill 50% width each. Default Holo styled tabs doesn't look that bad (as shown in previous link), but my styled tabs on this big screen look much worse.

PS: Situation doesn't change if I make a text in tabs bigger or longer. Tabs don't adujst their width, instead they change their height and text takes 2 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, this is a another JB changes:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b8139af3dcae80c0030afd0354dc424a7c72c3d9

One of solution: set target SDK 15 or lower.

Comment: Thx for the info & valuable link, I think that this might be the cause. I tried setting targetSDK to 15 & lower, but unforutnatelly, it haven't solved it :-/